# JAVA - subList returns empty lists inside FOR loop

Tags: java

I'm facing with the following issue.
I have a List TOTAL (size: S) and I need to split it in N contiguous blocks. Here the code:

```
int start_index, end_index;

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            start_index = (S/N)*i;
            end_index = start_index + (S/N) - 1;
            List<String> SUBblock = TOTAL.subList(start_index, end_index-1);
            System.out.println("block "+i+": from "+start_index+" to "+end_index);
            System.out.println("block "+i+": "+SUBblock .toString());
        }
```

Indexes are correct: the first `System.out.println` works fine.
But `SUBblock` is always empty.
A subList call outside the for loop works fine: for example, `TOTAL.subList(0,2)` returns the first and the second element as expected.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: what is a _`List TOTAL (size: S)`_?? You created it in a small size?

Comment: @Jordi A `List<String>` named `TOTAL`, whose size is `S`

Comment: `end_index - 1` looks suspicious. You know that end index passed to `subList` is not included, right?

Comment: uhm I see... `S` is a final variable? which value?... would be nice to put here important objects involved into the problem....

Comment: @Arkadiy It should be `end_index+1` (typing error).  Now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in calculation of  Start and End Index. Try with following code.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        start_index = (S/N)*i;
        end_index = start_index + (S/N);
        List<String> SUBblock= (TOTAL.subList(start_index, end_index)); 

        System.out.println("block "+i+": from "+start_index+" to "+end_index);
        System.out.println("block "+i+": "+SUBblock .toString());
    }
```